# I can't find a solution with my code about the "polyfill" problem

Tags: javascript, polyfills

I have a problem with the polyfill in my code. I tried to find a solution to this, but I couldn't find it.

It displays this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal error opening backing store for indexedDB.open.
 at wrappedSendMessageCallback (browser-polyfill.js:1163:16) wrappedSendMessageCallback @ browser-polyfill.js:1163 await in wrappedSendMessageCallback (asynchrone) (anonyme) @ index.js:92 (anonyme) @ index.js:92 (anonyme) @ index.js:92 polyfill.js:1193 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal error opening backing store for indexedDB.open.
 at wrappedSendMessageCallback (polyfill.js:1193:18) wrappedSendMessageCallback @ polyfill.js:1193 browser-polyfill.js:1163 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal error opening backing store for indexedDB.open. 
 at wrappedSendMessageCallback (browser-polyfill.js:1163:16)
```

I downloaded 2 files from "polyfill.io":

```
polyfill-service-main ,
polyfill-service-self-hosted-main,
```

Comment: If you can't come up with a reasonable explanation for the failure to open the backing store, you should file a bug with whoever made the polyfill.

Comment: If you file a bug report, be sure to mention browser version, how you included what files, and what exact JS you wrote to trigger the error. Same info would be needed for anybody here to help you.